# DB2 Select users from table and then order them

Tags: sql, db2, sql-order-by

I'm using DB2 database and I need to select users with the highest average transaction and then from those users select those who have the lowest variance, I tried something like:

```
     select p.Contact,                                                
     p.Avg,                                                    
     p.V                                                       
       from(                                                          
        select p1.id as Contact,                                 
           avg(p1.amount) as Avg,
           variance(p1.amount) as V
        from user.trnc p1                                       
        group by p1.id                                           
        order by Avg DESC) p                                                                                  
     order by V                                                    
     fetch first 50 rows only;
```

Probably I should make new table, but I'm new to sql and don't know how to do it properly in this case. Now my query just ordering users by lowest variance.
The table looks like:
User.Trnc:

1. ID - User ID
2. Amount - sum of transaction

Comment: You need to FETCH FIRST at the same place as ORDER BY avg.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you!